# How can I create a 3D spacetime grid animation?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, wireframe, proportional-editing

I want to make this kind of animation [GIF](https://blogs-images.forbes.com/startswithabang/files/2018/08/ezgif-5-014fc9ef71.gif).
It has to work in **Eevee** with multiple objects. Unfortunately I couldn't do it via **wireframes modifier** and **proportional editing**. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I think you want warp or hook modifiers instead of proportional editing. Wireframe should be okay.  I'll play around to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Okay, I got it working with a negative cast modifier of all things.  I'm writing up my solution currently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A similar (**though not physically realistic**) effect can be done using array modifiers and a wireframe modifier to create the 3 dimensional space-time lattice, and then a cast modifier to create the gravitational effect.

1. Start with a cube, and then add three array modifiers, one for each dimension, and then a wire frame modifier, as indicated:

[image: screenshot of blender]

This gives you the space time lattice. Apply these modifiers and then center the lattice on the origin, just to make everything else a little easier.

2. Add a sphere. Then add to the lattice a cast modifier, shape sphere, with a negative factor. The lower this factor is, the more gravitation is simulated.

[image]

Moving the sphere will distort the lattice as one *might* expect:

[image]

***Note well however*** that this effect is applied *linearly* over space, while real gravity would fall off proportionally to the inverse square. A more physically realistic effect I believe is possible using vertex groups and the hook modifier, but would be more complicated than this solution, which should be acceptable for most aesthetic uses.

Comment: This is amazing!! I just fell in love with lattice and cast modifier! :D

Answer (score 10):

Great answer from *jwrush*! - I'll add that with regards to texturing, this seems to do the trick. Make sure to select your "Warp sphere" as the Object basis for the Texture Coordinate. You may have to alter your mapping scale values and the ColorRamp sliders to accommodate the size of your objects.

[image: CubeTex]

Comment: Rad! I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this.

Comment: Why does this color ramp affect the whole Blender UI? :-)

Comment: Lol. Happy coincidence, I guess ;)

Comment: Is it possible to accept two answers?)

Comment: Na - only one accepted answer. It's all good though - leave it the way it is - the real "meat of the solution" is in _jwrush's_ answer - all I added with this answer is that a "sphere texture" makes a "color sphere" around a sphere ;)